# Can all factions hear proximity voice chat?

Tags: planetside-2

Planetside 2 has a nifty feature of proximity voice chat. Everyone in an area can hear it, but my question is can other factions hear your voice as well? Often times I will use proximity to corral the entire force instead of just my squad and I don't want the enemies knowing the plan.

If they do hear it how can you strategize a large force of multiple platoons/squads securely?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For better or worse, they cannot.

I'd argue the best option for mass communication is `/regionsay` (`/re`) which is everyone in your faction in the same hex (available to everyone) or `/orders`, which is available to squad leaders that spend certs on the channel.

You can communicate with other factions with `/yell` (`/y`), voice (`V` key) macros, and to a particular player with `/whisper <PLAYERNAME>` (`/w`).

Here's a link to an SOE forum thread discussing the decision:

https://forums.station.sony.com/ps2/index.php?threads/why-arent-we-allowed-to-hear-enemies-proximity-chat.111551/

Comment: Really? You can hear other factions when they use the stock numbered callouts.